# Adding remote rule in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, backbone.js

I'm trying to validate `email` field of my registration form, using jquery validation remoting rule.

Here is what I've tried :

```
$.validator.addMethod("isAlrdExist", function(value, element)
    {
        var inputElem = $('#registerForm :input[name="email"]'),
                data = { "email" : inputElem.val() },
                eReport = ''; //error report
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: getURL() + WebConfig.RACustomer + "?$filter=WebAccount eq '" + $("#email").val() + "'",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(res)
                    {
                        if (res.length != 0)
                        {
                            return '<p>This email address is already registered.</p>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

    }, '');


    $("#registerForm").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            email: {
                isAlrdExist: true
            }
        }
    });
```

**Problem** : when I do `console.log($("#registerForm").valid());`, on click Register button, even `email` is not yet existed in database, but the result is `false`.

Any idea what could be causing this.

Comment: [isAlrdExist]'s binded function return nothing. ajax's callback function's return value have no meaning in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear that you can shoehorn everything you want into a default [remote](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) rule, but it's worth trying.

```
$('#registerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            remote: {
                url:getURL() + WebConfig.RACustomer,  //will only work if this is static relative to the form
                data: {
                    "email" : function(){
                         return $('#registerForm input[name="email"]').val();
                     },
                     "$filter" : function() {
                         return "WebAccount eq '"+$('#email').val()+"'"
                     }
                },
                dataType:'html',
                type:'GET',
                //fiddle with the data here to ultimately return an error message or true
                dataFilter:function(data){
                   if (data.length != 0){
                       return '<p>This email address is already registered.</p>';
                   }else{
                       return true;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I made a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/fhpr52ca/

Comment: `true` is still returned before ajax execution. So when I fill in `email` textbox then click on `register` button, `console.log(data)` in `dataFilter` id done after returning `true`.

Comment: That shouldn't matter?  Internally, the validate plugin should wait until the ajax call resolves before submitting the form.  Although it's not clear from your comment, but the dataFilter function is called *after* the AJAX call completes.  I did notice that I had a typo in there (I called the result `data` but used `res` which obviously wasn't right).

Comment: I do follow your answer, and console.long `$("#registerForm").valid()` while clicking on register button. then the result is come out before dataFilter working :/

Comment: OK well, no.  That's not what happens.  See my edit with example.  I also had to change the `dataType` to `html`.  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/fhpr52ca/